# undefined is not an object this.props.auth from redux

Tags: react-native, redux, promise

I am trying to navigate to a different screen on success of my authentication function. This is the approach I'm taking, but I am getting `undefined is not an object` when I try to use `.then()`

This is my code

```
login = () => {
    const {username, password} = this.state
    this.props.authentication(username, password).then(res => {

    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        authentication: (username, password) =>
            dispatch(authenticationLoginEmail(username, password)),
    };
};
```

This my redux code

```
export const authenticationLoginEmail = (username, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authLoginEmailStart())
        axios.post('url',{username, password})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data.idusers,'ID USERS');
            ...
            dispatch(authLoginEmailSuccess(idusers, token))
            return res
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            dispatch(authLoginEmailfail(err))
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

#### Error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.authentication(username, password).then')
```

thanks for helping

Comment: so why this happend ? anybody can explain to me? thankss

Comment: It would be helpful if you put the actual error code. Like, what file the error code is coming from, and what line the error is on? My guess, based on what you've shown so far, is that `this.state` might not be available where you're using it?

Comment: hmm so when i click login its throw error when im using .then after this.props.authentication because i want to navigate to other screen when success

Comment: Does `this.props.authentication` return a promise?

Comment: yes i want to return promise but i got that erorr

Comment: Can you add the code for the `this.props.authentication` function to your post?

Comment: im already post that code on above authenticationLoginEmail

Comment: So the name difference is intentional?

Comment: hmm yes but i think its not a problem, you can check another code from above i.ve already update, mapDispatchToProps

Comment: What about assigning the result of your function to a variable? `const result = this.props.authentication(username, password);`? Otherwise, you may need to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Personally I use [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.js.org/) and [`generators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: oke i'll try thankss

Comment: it works i'm using async/await , thanks

Comment: Cool, I put my answer below for future readers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you should not use it like promise

`this.props.authentication(username, password).then(res => { })`

if you want to a response you have to just call this in your code

`this.props.authentication(username, password);`

And if your fetch finished you will send your success or error into redux state

`dispatch(authLoginEmailSuccess(idusers, token))`
or
`dispatch(authLoginEmailfail(err))`

and you can save your state in reducer and then get it into your component in  `mapStateToProps`